# How to write a secure application in python?

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

Say you write a python application that interacts with a webserver. The application secures your traffic with public-private key encryption (e.g. RSA). How can you prevent someone to read the program in a normal text editor and extract your private key?

Comment: Dont save the private key directly in the program.

Comment: You could always generate a key on the fly, and do key-exchange, or use libraries to connect via https...

Comment: @ChrisDoyle no but then they must be stored somewhere else on the system

Comment: @EdWard so a new key each session?

Comment: yes somewhere else. that can be in the enviroment variable if only you have access to. It could be in a file with permissions for only your user to access. It could be in some sort of vault or secure keychain to which when you run the program you are prompted for the password that you must enter to unlock the vault and the code to retrieve the private key. The moral of the story is your python code will always be readable so dont put your private key in it. Put the private key somewhere else that only you can read or where they key is protected with a layer of security like a password

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I would suggest that that's probably the easiest way to ensure you can't have it stolen - even if you go for some kind of session that can be renewed, given you'd have to write it to the disk for next time, what's to stop someone reading it? Obviously, you could still have some kind of token, but, like I said, I can't think of a way to store it securely... Or, as @ChrisDoyle said, you could encrypt it with a password which the user has to type in each time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually user applications that interact with a webserver have 2 methods for authentication.

1-Session authentication: you need to login to the webserver for the server to give you access to the pages or information you need.

2-Token authentication: The server can generate a token that the user can send with the requests.

On the other hand if its an application that only you are going to use you can set the private keys in the environment variables of your operating system and then fetch them using python.

```
API_SECRET = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")
```

Comment: So basically storing them somewhere else and let the server check them?